# Why is Utf8JsonReader.TokenType required with JsonConvert<int>, but not JsonConvert<double>

Tags: c#, deserialization, system.text.json

In order to be able to deserialize the following JSON:

```
[
    {
        "name": "Luke Skywalker",
        "height": "172",
        "mass": "77",
        "birth_year": "19BBY",
        "gender": "male"
    }
]
```

into the following record:

```
record class Character
{
    public string Name { get; init; } = "";

    [property: JsonPropertyName("birth_year")]
    public double Birth { get; init; }

    public int Height { get; init; }

    [property: JsonPropertyName("mass")]
    public int Weight { get; init; }

    public GenderEnum Gender { get; init; }
}
```

I use the following `JsonSerializerOptions`:

```
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions()
{
    PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true,
    NumberHandling = JsonNumberHandling.AllowReadingFromString,
    Converters =
    {
        new GenderEnumConverter(),
        new BirthYearConverter(),
        new MeasurementsConverter()
    }
};
```

**Problem:**

Two of these Converters handle string-to-double and string-to-int deserialization, respectively:

```
class BirthYearConverter : JsonConverter<double>
{
    public override double Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        return double.TryParse(reader.GetString()?.TrimEnd('B', 'b', 'Y', 'y'), out double result) ? result : 0;
    }
    
    // ...
}

class MeasurementsConverter : JsonConverter<int>
{
    public override int Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.String && options.NumberHandling == JsonNumberHandling.AllowReadingFromString)
        {
            return int.TryParse(reader.GetString(), out int result) ? result : -1;
        }

        return reader.GetInt32();
    }

    // ...
}
```

These converters are necessary. If you are not familiar with swapi.dev/api, the numeric values are presented as strings and can include invalid integer or floating point property values.

With the above code everything runs as expected.

But the odd thing to observe here is that the int converter can't be simplified like the double one. I am forced to check for the `TokenType`. If I don't do that and try a similar approach to the double converter and use `int.TryParse(reader.GetString()...` I will get the following exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Cannot get the value of a token type 'String' as a number.'

**So my question is**, why was I forced to explicitly handle strings in the `JsonConverter<int>` converter to avoid an `InvalidOperationException`, but that wasn't required of me when using `JsonConverter<double>` where I was able to make use of `reader.GetString()`?

**Note:** For additional information, you can refer to the [separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73998857/cannot-deserialize-a-string-to-an-int-despite-having-a-converter-and-jsonnumber?noredirect=1#comment130657441_73998857) that originated this one.

Comment: Please share the stacktrace of excpetion

Comment: @Amir That isn't required. I updated the original question to include additional information.

Comment: Just see this dude ;-) https://source.dot.net/#System.Text.Json/System/Text/Json/Reader/Utf8JsonReader.TryGet.cs,02b55254c0b3b478,references.  
you can the go through TryGetInt32 and see the error ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MeasurementsConverter` seems to be kind of pointless. Specifying `NumberHandling = JsonNumberHandling.AllowReadingFromString` should be enough (at least for sample JSON):

```cs
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions()
{
    PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true,
    NumberHandling = JsonNumberHandling.AllowReadingFromString,
    Converters =
    {
        new GenderEnumConverter(),
        new BirthYearConverter()
    }
};
```

As for the question - you would be required to do the same in `JsonConverter<double>` because `reader.GetDouble()` will throw as `reader.GetInt32()` did, you just don't call it because you need to sanitize the string so you go straight to the `reader.GetString()`. I.e. complete analog of your `JsonConverter<double>` approach would look like:

```
class MeasurementsConverter : JsonConverter<int>
{
    public override int Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        return int.TryParse(reader.GetString(), out int result) ? result : -1;
    }
    // ...
}
```

In current implementation [`Utf8JsonReader.GetString()`](https://source.dot.net/#System.Text.Json/System/Text/Json/Reader/Utf8JsonReader.TryGet.cs,34) always throws if the token type is not a valid one. So if you provide both `double` and `int` values as numbers in the source JSON, they both will fail with the same error (without explicit handling for `JsonTokenType.String`). I.e.:

```json
[
    {
        "name": "Luke Skywalker",
        "height": "172",
        "mass": 77,
        "birth_year": "19BBY",
        "gender": "male"
    }
]
```

will fail with the same error (*"Cannot get the value of a token type 'Number' as a string."*) as:

```json
[
    {
        "name": "Luke Skywalker",
        "height": "172",
        "mass": "77",
        "birth_year": 19,
        "gender": "male"
    }
]
```

Comment: This question had its origin here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73998857/cannot-deserialize-a-string-to-an-int-despite-having-a-converter-and-jsonnumber?noredirect=1#comment130657441_73998857. Unfortunately, Setting `NumberHandling` to read from strings is not enough.

Comment: @AlexandreBell can you please explain what I'm missing - cause it [works for me](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0qsWjm)

Comment: @AlexandreBell see the update. The only difference it seems that you are not getting numer values for doubles, i.e. in source json `birth_year` is always actually a string.

Comment: I don't know what happened. But you are right. It does work. I don't know why it wasn't before. What could I have been doing that would lead me to that exception and that now it isn't. Seems like a waste of everyone's time... apologies.

Comment: @AlexandreBell NP, was glad to help! And again - it can be fluctuation in the source data. The `JsonNumberHandling.AllowReadingFromString` for sure will not parse non-number strings.